# Simple Question: Cut Number in Transfer function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, factorization

Given transfer function:

$W=\frac{10 (s+100)}{2 s^4+219 s^3+1909 s^2+900 s+1000}$

```
W=(1000 + 10 s)/(1 (1000 + 900 s + 1909 s^2 + 219 s^3 + 2 s^4))
```

Which command to use to reduce the coefficients for the variable $s$?

I mean to make it so that :

$W=\frac{0.01s+1}{0.002 s^4+0.0219s^3+1.9s^2+0.9s+1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many methods. Here I take the numerator and denominator. It is not clear what you mean by reduce the coefficients for the variable s but I make the constant coefficient of the denominator 1.0.

```
W = (1000 + 10 s)/(1 (1000 + 900 s + 1909 s^2 + 219 s^3 + 2 s^4));
num = Numerator[W];
den = Denominator[W];
coff = Coefficient[den, s, 0];
num1 = num/coff // N // Expand;
den1 = den/coff // N // Expand;
num1/den1
```

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: I got almost the same thing. This is fine. Thank you for your help.